# Shell script. split line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have this file with user info

```
    darjak2:x:60919:100:Name Surname IF-3/3 2015-02-11:/export/home/darjak2:/bin/bash
    edvmic:x:60920:100:Name2 Surname2 IF-3/14 2015-02-11:/export/home/edvmic:/bin/bash
    darjak2:x:60519:100:Name3 Surname3 IF-3/3 2015-02-11:/export/home/darjak2:/bin/bash
    edvmic:x:60920:100:Name4 Surname4 IF-3/9 2015-02-11:/export/home/edvmic:/bin/bash
```

So here how I run my script

```
./aa IF-3/3
```

so I need to print all people names and surnames that are from `IF-3/3`

```
indx=0
kiekis=0
labas=$1
for i in $*
do
        indx=$(($indx+1))
        kiekis=$(grep $i /etc/passwd | wc -l)
        echo "Grupe " $i "Mokiniu kiekis " $kiekis> t$indx
awk -F: '{split($5,a,/[[:blank:]]+/); result=$(a[3])}' /etc/passwd
echo $result
done
```

So I split everything. And then try to do this `result=$(a[3])` and later I will check if result = $i. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A great question includes (1) an explanation of what you're trying to achieve, (2) your source code, (3) your input data, (4) your actual results and (5) your expected results.  You've supplied 2 and 3 (which is a great start), but if you could also describe what your goal is, it will help us tune our answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an if condition to check for `a[3]` is equal to `IF-3/3`, if yes then force the awk program to print `a[1]` and `a[2]`.

```
$ labas='IF-3/3'
$ awk -F: -v var="$labas" '{split($5,a,/[[:blank:]]+/);if(a[3]==var)print a[1],a[2]}' file
Name Surname
Name3 Surname3
```

seems like you already stored the first argument to `labas` variable. Use awk's `-v` parameter to pass shell variable's value to the awk.